# Where do I put haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml in the Android sample of JavaCV's FacePreview class?

Tags: android, javacv

There's a snippet of code in the Android sample's FacePreview class that boggles me:

```
File classifierFile = Loader.extractResource(getClass(),
        "/org/bytedeco/javacv/facepreview/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml",
        context.getCacheDir(), "classifier", ".xml");
```

I know I should change the names before `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` to match my project name, but I can't figure out where to actually put the XML file in my project structure.

I did read somewhere that I have to put the xml file in the same folder as the FacePreview class... so does that mean I have to put it in `src/main/java/<package_name>`?

Edit: That doesn't work either. Do I have to download and cache it in the Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it goes in `src/main/resources/org/bytedeco/javacv/facepreview/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`

assuming gradle does the right thing

Comment: That did the trick, though I'm still concerned with the `Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core;`. How do I resolve that Exception? And what's the difference between the 'res' and 'resources' folders in Android?

Comment: You need to include the `android-arm` artifact for the javacpp opencv library. `res` is android resource, `resources` is java resource

Comment: Did you mean `compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'`?

Comment: I don't use gradle, I wouldn't know